# after updating to iOS version 9.3.3, redirect url to launch app not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

In my app, I have a web view where I load the login screen(html page) to authenticate (OAuth). After the authentication succeeds i redirect the flow to my native app screen using custom URI scheme which i would receive in the response. This setup was working previously in iPhone device with version 9.2.1 until i updated to iOS version 9.3.3. Now I am not getting the proper redirect URL, and instead i am getting an error pop-up with message "Error: The URL can;t be shown"

I know lot of changes happened in the latest update released by apple, especially on webkit. Has anyone else faced similar issue? is it a bug in the new update ?

Would appreciate if anyone help me with the reason why the redirect failed after update ?

thanks in advance

Comment: same issue I am facing.. Have you find any solution?

Comment: Same here... I will give a bounty for the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Welcome to the Security Upgrade 9.3.3!** Deep Links!

1st You should embrace **Universal Links and forget about URL Schemes**...

Check this transition tutorial:
https://blog.branch.io/ios-9.2-deep-linking-guide-transitioning-to-universal-links

In case you don't want to use Universal Links...

Which delegate method are you using to get the Scheme call? I guess you are using:

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

In that specific case... Double check you don't have any &, +, / in the URL Scheme, lot of new encoding going on, if you do, convert those to % encoding, this is good:

Good:

```
myAppSchemeName://abc?param=AppleIsTough
```

Bad:

```
myAppSchemeName://abc&param=AppleIsTough
```

Fix your URL Scheme call and get done with it!

Be happy!

Comment: I am using the application(_ app: UIApplication,
                  openURL url: NSURL,
                  options options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool

Comment: I am getting wrong redirection URL in the webview delegate with NSURLErrorDomani error code 101 which says "The URL can't be shown". Hence the appdelegate is not being called at all.

Comment: The URL scheme does not contain any of those characters and is similar to 'Good' as you have described above.

Comment: HEY! Could you try just the appName://HELLO and check out if you can get it? Have you tried the ultimately solution which is the Universal Links?

Comment: That works, but the issue is, we receive the url from a server redirect response. We were receiving it in all previous versions, but not in iOS v9.3.3. The wenview delegate is not receiving this url.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is duplicate of [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42357068/ios-10-custom-url-scheme-no-longer-working), which seems to be solved by questioner. but answer is a bit ambiguous.

so here is the concrete way at least solve the issue in my environment (iOS 10.3 device and iOS 9.0 & 10.3 simulator), which I think the idea is same as above source, that is, responding html page and do redirect in this page, like below.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location = "com.your.scheme://a/b?foo=bar";
    }, 1);
</script>
<h1>redirect...</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Its quite symptomatic treatment (like using setTimeout) and probably blocked by future iOS release, but I put here for the people who still have to use URL scheme for reason.